# How can JavaScript call a callback function from an object and function name as a string?

Tags: javascript, callback

How can I make my JavaScript library that gets passed a callback function as a string name of a callback function that is in another object/lib call it?

Example callback object that has the cb function:

```
var cb = {
  cb_function: function(data){
    console.log('[message_handler_callback ran from another objects function]', data);
  }
}
```

---

My JS library has the object name and function name stored like this...

```
if(typeof(that.message_handlers[i].callback) === 'string') {
    // needs to call cb.cb_function(data)
}
```

So how can my code above call:

```
cb.cb_function(data);
```

when `cb.cb_function` is stored as a string value in `that.message_handlers[i].callback`?

Comment: Don't store strings. Store functions.

Comment: @Bergi in this case it can be either

Comment: If the functions are properties of an object you can use square bracket notation: `myLib[callback]()`. You could also map strings to differently named functions.

Comment: @JasonDavis No, don't. Leave that to the caller of your library.